# Django Rest Framework Serializer Custom validations

Tags: django-rest-framework

is it necessary to write custom validation for serializers? My model and serializer are below.

**model**

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        unique=True,
        validators=[RegexValidator(regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-]*$")],
    )
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    playlist_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=get_upload_path,
        default="playlist/default/default.jpg",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=["jpg", "jpeg", "png"])],
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        Common.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinal_user)
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

**serializer**

```
class PlaylistSerailizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = "__all__"
```

Any answer is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try that to see what happens?

Comment: No need, if you define in models then serializer will use those

Comment: additional to the definition in my model, I want to validate file size  of the field `playlist_image`

Comment: Yes you need custom validation for file sizes, but its also a bad idea to do it in python, a better option is to limit this in nginx/apache. Else you need to upload the whole file and then error out, doing it in the webserver will fail before the file is uploaded.